# Javascript element event delegation

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have set up a demo of parent listening for events on children. I dont understand why the following examle works with click event and not with mouseenter?

```js
const on = (element, type, selector, handler) => {
  element.addEventListener(type, (event) => {
    if (event.target.closest(selector)) {
      handler(event);
    }
  });
};

var a = document.querySelector('.a')

;
on(a, 'click', '.b', (event) => console.log('click'));
on(a, 'mouseenter', '.b', (event) => console.log('mouseenter'))
```

```html
<div class="a">
<div class="b">this is b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As @Quentin pointed out in a comment, the target is always the triggering element.  So "closest" may not work as you expect.  With the mouseenter event it will always return null because it doesn't bubble up from the child element.  And with the mouseover event it will return null when triggered by the parent element or the child when triggered by child. In other words, "closest" is not doing anything useful in this case.  Good question +1

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event):

> Though similar to mouseover, mouseenter differs in that **it doesn't bubble** and it isn't sent to any descendants when the pointer is moved from one of its descendants' physical space to its own physical space.

Event delegation depends on the event bubbling from the element that triggered the event to the element where the event handler is bound.

Consider using `mouseover` instead.

Comment: Up vote as this was new to me.  Yet, wouldn't OP's code still fail since it use "closest" to try to find a child element, i.e., doesn't it always look toward the root?

Comment: @Yogi — `event.target` is the element that triggers the event, which will be either the element on which the event listener is bound, or (if the event bubbles) a descendant of that element.

Comment: mouseover will trigger multiple times if target element contains child elements. thats why I have mouseenter.

Comment: @Toniq — So compare `event.target` directly instead of using `closest`.

Comment: Like this?  if (event.target == selector || event.target.closest(selector)) {
       handler(event);
      }

Comment: No. `if (event.target.matches(selector) { ... }`. (If you want the function to be generic then you'll need to special case mouseover to decide if you are going to use `matches` or `selector`)

Comment: That still doesnt seem to work:  https://jsfiddle.net/7ky58owv/

Comment: @Toniq — You're still using `mouseenter` which still doesn't bubble. So the event listener on `.a` gets a `mouseover` event when `.a` is entered, tests to see if it was triggered on `.b` (which it wasn't) and stops. A `mouseenter` event is also fired on `.b` but it doesn't bubble and there is no event listener attached to `.b`.

Comment: How does jQuery handle this then?  If I cannot attach event to parent to listen on its children (which there are many) .

Comment: I don't know and have no desire to dig through its source code to find out. My recommendation is still to use `mouseover` instead of `mouseenter`.